# Convert base64 string to int for cryptographic use in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to do some simple cryptography using golang.

I have an RSA public key in form of base64 encoded modulo and exponent.
I want to use that values to instantiate [rsa.PublicKey struct](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#PublicKey).

Converting modulo base64 string to big.Int looks pretty straightforward for me.

Unexpectedly, I had a lot of trouble trying to convert base64 string to simple int (the exponent part of RSA key).

The best thing I've came up with:

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/base64"
        "fmt"
        "math/big"
)

func main() {
        e_data, _ := base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString("AQAB")

        e_big := new(big.Int)
        e_big.SetBytes(e_data)
        e := int(e_big.Int64())

        // Finally I have an int here to use it in rsa.PublicKey struct
        fmt.Println(e)
}
```

Is there any better, more simple way to convert base64 string to int?

Comment: you mean `e := int(new(big.Int).SetBytes(e_data).Int64())`? You could encoding/binary, but then you have to pad the slice yourself.

Comment: @JimB Yes, that's exactly what I meant. But that solution still looks too complex for such a simple use case. May be I've spent to little time using Go and just not used to it yet.

Comment: Normally you would probably use `encoding/binary`, but since your data is only 3 bytes you have to pad it out yourself, which doesn't look any cleaner -- `int(binary.BigEndian.Uint32(append(make([]byte, 4-len(eData)), eData...)))`

Comment: Also, don’t forget that the RFC suggests only 65537, so you could probably just map the base64 value directly to the exponent. (In reality there are only a few other exponents in use, but they are rarely encountered.)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/base64"
   "encoding/binary"
)

func decode(s string) (uint32, error) {
   a, e := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s)
   if e != nil { return 0, e }
   return binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(append(a, 0)), nil
}

func main() {
   n, e := decode("AQAB")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   println(n == 65537)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary

Comment: Why the `append(a, 0)`?